# SVG does not appear sometime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angular-material

I have a strange problem with an SVG image in my list. Sometimes (not very often!!) when a new user is added to the list, the SVG image is loaded (I can see it in the DOM) but nothing appears in the browser.

I use **Angular Material 1.09** and I initialize this icon in a config block using the $mdIconProvider:

```
...
$mdIconProvider
    .icon('sketch:pencil', '/content/images/sketch-cursor.svg');
...
```

and my list look like this:

```
<md-list flex="">                        
    <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-attr-title="{{user.name + (user.own ? ' (ME)' : '')}}">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="sketch:pencil" ng-class="user.iconColor"></md-icon>
        <div class="md-list-item-text xs-min-width-80">
            <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 72" width="30" height="30"><defs><filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%"><feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3.5" dy="3.5"/><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="4"/><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/></filter></defs><path fill-opacity="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" filter="url(#shadow)" d="M16.16,33.81l-3-.76c-1-.26-1.42-0.09-1.71.93Q9.88,39.89,8.34,45.82a1.11,1.11,0,0,0,.3.87q4.38,4.43,8.82,8.81a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.13.31c3.84-1,7.66-2,11.48-3.08,1.17-.32,1.34-0.69,1-1.86-0.22-.8-0.41-1.61-0.64-2.4a2.77,2.77,0,0,1,.82-2.94q3.38-3.35,6.73-6.72L58.28,18.48c1.52-1.52,1.81-1.45,2.37.6,0.36,1.33.65,2.69,1,4A2,2,0,0,1,61,25.28Q51.25,35,41.57,44.67c-3,3-5.92,6-8.94,8.95a5.28,5.28,0,0,1-2.22,1.21Q17.16,58.44,3.89,61.94a1.69,1.69,0,0,1-1.39-.22,1.72,1.72,0,0,1-.23-1.41Q5.81,47,9.44,33.63a5.17,5.17,0,0,1,1.26-2.18c5.93-6,11.91-11.95,17.87-17.91C32,10.08,35.5,6.63,38.92,3.12a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.31-1c1.36,0.37,2.73.72,4.09,1.12,1,0.3,1.14.78,0.41,1.58-0.21.23-.43,0.44-0.65,0.66L18.85,32.73A3.08,3.08,0,0,1,16.16,33.81M28.58,44.7a4.93,4.93,0,0,1-1-.56q-3.77-3.74-7.52-7.5A1.23,1.23,0,0,1,20,34.76c0.28-.33.57-0.65,0.87-1L48.14,6.57c1.25-1.25,1.65-1.25,2.88,0l6.6,6.6c1.19,1.19,1.2,1.63,0,2.81l-18.92,19q-4.4,4.41-8.82,8.81A11.34,11.34,0,0,1,28.58,44.7Z" /></svg>
```

I see also in the DOM that the filter ID in the SVG file is also modified and a "cacheX" (X is an index) is added to the ID. Is it something that come from a cache mechanism in the $mdIconProvider.

**UPDATE**

It look like the problem comes from the SVG file. If I remove the filter from the SVG, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a CodePen? You can fork this - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/RRgKYa

Comment: It will be hard to provide a CodePen, I was able to reproduce this but I need two tabs open. It's really weird. To explain the context, the list show online user. When I refresh one tab, the user disappear in the other one and when he reappaering, the SVG is not display... Really really weird...

Comment: And when I say it's weird, in the Chrome dev tool, if I uncheck the Angular Material style md-icon svg { display: block }, the SVG is shown...

Comment: I removed the filter from my SVG file and it works... Chrome bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a good enough solution (maybe there's another one!). After multiple reads about problems with the SVG filter and Chrome, I've decided to remove the shadow from my SVG and it's solved the problem:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 72" width="30" height="30"><path fill-opacity="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" d="..." /></svg>
```